# What content/factors increase a C++ programs exe file size?

Tags: debugging, build, size, executable, release

Can someone explain exactly what factors, in detail, increases an executable's file output size in C++? Things I know that increase file sizes from testing are, including libraries, and built in variable types. I also read somewhere on here that build modes(release vs debug) can also increase exe file size? What I'm not sure of is if the actual value size in a variable like int with a value of 5, vs int with a value of 100,000,000, increase exe size, if the number of actual lines in the program (depends on the lines content) plays a role, and what other factors increases the .exe file size.

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug vs Release

In debug mode, there are sometimes debuginfos in the .exe file, sometimes they are in an external pdb file. (Depending on the compile used).
Furthermore, often the debug mode has less optimizations and uses a lot more instructions. (Like loading and storing a variable unnecessary often).
On the other hand, in release builds, some optimizations are applied. They can have both effects. They either increase the size of the file (like function inlining or loop unrolling) or the decrease the size (Removing unneccessary instructions or merge them).
Furthermore symbols are often stripped away in release builds.

2. Static vs dynamic linking

If you link statically, all required files/functions are included in the final executable ==> Bigger executable (Often)
If you link dynamically, only a reference to the library is in the final executable, so the filesize is smaller.

3. (C++ specific) Templates

Templates increase the size of the file really much, as for each type, where the template is applied, machine code has to be generated.
Because of this, if you make heavy use of templates (Like using Boost), you will get a big executable.

> What I'm not sure of is if the actual value size in a variable like int with a value of 5, vs int with a value of 100,000,000, increase exe size

There won't be a difference, because both will take 4 bytes. EXCEPT if the compiler decides to optimize and uses only one byte for 5. Like:

```
mov al, 5 ;(Save some bytes)
vs
mov eax, 5
```

> if the number of actual lines in the program [...] plays a role

Yes, more lines, more code. But you can't translate the lines of code to the size of the executable. Consider:

```
void foo(int a,
         int b,
         int c,
         double d) 
{
    if (a<50)
    {
      baz(a);
    }
    //Do something
}
```

vs

```
void foo(int a,int b,int c, double d){
   if(a<50) baz(a);
}
```

All of them will compile to the same code. Furthermore comments don't count to the executable, except if a compiler would decide to add comments into the executable (I don't know any compiler, that is doing something like that).